# How do I write Image Binary Data into local file system using Node.js services on webOS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webos, mojo, enyo

I am trying to write image data received from Evernote `getResourceData`-method, into local system in JavaScript code using Node.js. The image file is getting saved successfully, but looks like it is corrupted, and I'm not able to open it.

The function `getResourceData` returns binary data of the resource with the provided GUID. For example, if this were an image resource, this would contain the raw bits of the image.

- Hex of original: http://i41.tinypic.com/ev8bnr.jpg
- Hex of downloaded: http://i41.tinypic.com/10rs7zm.jpg

Here's the code:

**Client.js**:

```
var onSuccess = function(resource, transport) {
  self.showResourceData(resource);
  //console.log("Got Resource: "+resource);
};
NoteStore.getResourceData(onSuccess,this.showAlertMessage.bind(this, 
    "Failed to get Resource"), inSender.getValue());

showResourceData: function(resource) {
  //Calls WriteFileAssistant service
  this.$.writeFile.call({ path: "/downloads/logo1.png", content: resource });
}
```

**WriteFileAssistant.js**:

```
WriteFileAssistant.prototype.run = function(future) {
  var filePath = this.controller.args.path;
  var content = this.controller.args.content;

  var downloadfile = fs.createWriteStream(filePath,
      {'flags': 'w', encoding: 'binary'});
  downloadfile.write(content, encoding='binary', function(err) {
    future.result = { path: filePath, bytes: content.length, error: err };
  });
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

-Petro

Comment: You seem to be using named arguments to `downloadfile.write()` in `WriteFileAssistant.js`. I believe that isn't valid JavaScript. Also, you could shorten your code a bit by using [`fs.writeFile()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/fs.html#fs.writeFile)

Comment: @Morten Siebuhr, I also tried using fs.writeFile(), as shown below, instead of using last 2 lines in above code. But, still same result.

fs.writeFile(filePath, content, encoding='binary', function(err) { future.result = { path: filePath, bytes: content.length, error: err }; });

Comment: Sorry to be so dense, but this example doesn't make sense. Where is `this.controller.args.content` being set? What is `this.$.writeFile`? It's the collecting of `content` for `downloadFile.write` that is most likely the issue but you haven't included any of that process here.

Comment: @Kato, this code is written in Mojo / Enyo Service framework, WriteFileAssistant.js is exposed as a service, `this.$.writeFile` invokes run method of WriteFileAssistant, and while calling this service, we set two parameters, `{ path: "/downloads/logo1.png", content: resource }`... these parameters are accessed in the service as shown below. 
  
`var filePath = this.controller.args.path;
var content = this.controller.args.content;`

Comment: Ah, well that makes some sense; let's add a couple tags, shall we? On troubleshooting, I'd still suggest that the generation of `content` is as likely as the write stream to be the culprit.

Comment: @Kato, yes I also suspect the same, `content` we get from evernote method, `getResourceData`... also, if we look at the HEX images, only few characters are different... but not sure why they are different :(

Comment: Your path needs to be "/media/internal/downloads" to be able to write a file.  There's no write-access to the root of the system filesystem.